# Why direct conversion to Char is deprecated for Double and Long types in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, starting from version 1.5, direct conversion to `Char` for `Double` and `Long` types has marked as **deprecated**, and it is recommended to invoker the following `toInt().toChar()` a chain of functions to convert `Double`/`Long` to `Char`.

What **prompted** the Kotlin developers to abandon the direct conversion to `Char` for `Double` and `Long` types?

What issues can this approach **avoid**?

```
fun main() {
    val l = 100_000_000_000 // random big number
    val d = 1.2543534645645362E15 // random big double

    var chUsedDirectToChar = l.toChar()
    var chUsedToIntToChar = l.toInt().toChar() // the same
    println(chUsedDirectToChar == chUsedToIntToChar) // true

    chUsedDirectToChar = d.toChar()
    chUsedToIntToChar = d.toInt().toChar() // the same
    println(chUsedDirectToChar == chUsedToIntToChar) // true
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the motivation in this KEEP: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/char-int-conversions.md

> Reverse conversions like `Double.toChar()` usually make no sense, and it would be more clear if the intent was expressed explicitly by converting the number to `Int` first and then getting the character corresponding to that Int code.

It is hard to understand what is the char you want for number such as `16.284619`, so now you have to explicitly convert it to `Int` and then to `Char`